# Setting up SSL with GRPC - ALPN not found

Tags: java, ssl, grpc, alpn

I want to set-up SSL on my GRPC server.
Here is what I'm doing:

```
Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(8080)
                    .useTransportSecurity(certChain, privateKey)
                    .addService(new HelloWorldService())
                    .build();
```

Now I get a ClassnotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at io.grpc.netty.JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured(JettyTlsUtil.java:34)
    at io.grpc.netty.GrpcSslContexts.selectApplicationProtocolConfig(GrpcSslContexts.java:153)
    ... 5 more
```

If we look into *JettyTlsUtil.isJettyAlpnConfigured()* method, we will see
      **Class.forName("org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN", true, null);**

Now, I have ALPN in my classpath. Also I have set up my dependencies according to the table presented here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#transport-security-tls

Folks at gRPC don't recommend using JDK as SSLProvider. Therefore, I've downloaded **io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL** , which is an SSLProvider by OpenSSL. 
Yet, gRPC doesn't recognize I have OpenSSL available here:

```
  /**
   * Returns OpenSSL if available, otherwise returns the JDK provider.
   */
  private static SslProvider defaultSslProvider() {
    return OpenSsl.isAvailable() ? SslProvider.OPENSSL : SslProvider.JDK;
  }
```

**EDIT:**
I was able to make it work by adding a VM argument -javaagent:C:/path/to/jetty-alpn-agent.jar

This makes it work with JDK as SSL provider. I still don't understand why grpc doesn't recognize I have OpenSSL available. I do have `netty-tcnative-boringssl-static` in my classpath.

Comment: What platform are you running on? Examples: 64 bit Windows, OS X, 32 bit Ubuntu Linux. Instead of Jetty ALPN, running on Java 11 (anything 9+) is another option.

Comment: I am running on 64-bit Windows and using Java 8. And upgrading java is definitely out of question, sadly. Do I have another way out of the situation?

Comment: Hmm... 64-bit Windows should work. Check `gradle dependencies` to see if the right versions are being selected. Since grpc 1.12 you should see logged INFO output like "netty-tcnative unavailable (this may be normal)" that provides an exception as to why it failed to load. Please provide that.

Comment: Apparently the tcnativeboring I downloaded contained 64-bit .dll file, yet I was running on a 32-bit JVM. Everything works now